# Why does it take more time to reach view after crossing middleware in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

These are following middleware in my project:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [ 
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  'simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware',
  'apps.quiz.totaltimemid.TimeCalculateMiddleware',
  ]
```

My custom middleware to measure time for reaching process_view of last middleware to my target view(class QuizFetchView(APIView)):

```
class TimeCalculateMiddleware(object):

    def process_view(self, request, callback, callback_args, 
        callback_kwargs):
        self.req_start_time = time.time()


    def process_response(self,request, response):
        try :
            response['vreach_time'] = float(response['tt_start']) - self.req_start_time
            return response
        except :
            return response
```

Target view:

```
class QuizFetchView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsAuthenticatedForRunningQuiz]
    def get(self, request: Request, key: str) -> Response:
        tt_start = time.time()
        .............. 
        .............. 
        ............
        Response['tt_start'] = tt_start
        return Response
```

For Login request middleware to view take very few milliseconds but subsequent request other than login take 25-35ms to reach view.

Please help me, Thank you

Comment: It would be very hard to find out why it is slow without looking at the code that you've removed. There could be a number of reasons this is happening. First among them would be a poorly indexed query.

Comment: I want to calculate the time it takes to reach target view

Comment: Ah I mis-understood the question. BTW how are you able to this `Response['tt_start'] = tt_start` without any exceptions. Isin't response a Type? I was trying to replicate your code in my side but this was throwing an error.

Comment: Response =  Response(response_obj) \n Response['tt_start'] = tt_start
        return Response

Answer (score 0):

NB : None of this is actually a proper answer, but this was a bit too long and complex for a comment.

First point: exception handlers don't come for free when an exception is triggered, so you really want to replace your try/except block with a containment test, ie :

```
if "tt_start" in response:
   response['vreach_time'] = float(response['tt_start']) - self.req_start_time

return response
```

Second point: middlewares are instanciated once at process start and reused thru the whole process life, so you should not rely too much on the middleware's instances variables. That might more or less work on a "multi-singlethreaded-processes" configuration but is garanteed to break on a multithread environment. IOW, you'd better store `start_time` on the request itself.

Third point: storing `tt_start` on the response is debatable, but are you *sure* you want to make it a response header ?

EDIT : should have got myself a coffee and read your snippet a second time before saying you were recording the whole view execution time too. So wrt/ the effective question, answer is : I don't have clue yet, sorry ;)

Finally, if what you want is to identify bottlenecks, a proper profiler might be a better tool.

Comment: My custom middleware's process_view is the last process_view executed, at that time I record the time and when execution of code of target view start I record that time and take the difference of these times, and the difference is about 30 ms, even though I don't use my middleware it take nearly same time as it was taking earlier.

Comment: @VickyGupta indeed, should have read your code snippet a second time, sorry (answer edited).